Reference Request: Second Order ZFC
I've seen a fair bit of discussion about second order ZFC (Second order ZFC, intuition required, How is second-order ZFC defined?, A question about Second-Order ZF and the Axiom of Choice, A question about Second-Order ZFC and the Continuum Hypothesis) but I can't find anything about it in my books. Are there good books which explain second order ZFC? Currently I'm asking just out of general interest.

Stewart Shapiro, Foundations without Foundationalism: A Case for Second-order Logic (Clarendon, 1991), Ch.5.4 Set theory.
